# What does the setCleanup method do on a LandingPad?

Tags: llvm

What does the setCleanUp(true) actually do when applied to a landing pad and what is the effect of not doing it.

I have this code

```
LLVM.SetCleanup(pad, true);
```

(which is LLVMSharp) and this works fine for catching and handling exceptions, but if I remove it, the code still works fine, so what does this actually do and what is the effect of *not* doing it?  The LLVM docs just say `Indicate that this landingpad instruction is a cleanup` but not what its effect is.  Or in other words what is an example of a landingpad that is not a cleanup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanup landing pads can be used for things like calling destructors when unwinding the stack. Generally, cleanup clauses are *always* executed, whereas non-cleanup landing pads would be used for actually *handling* exceptions, and only entered if the type of the exception matches the type specified by the landing pad.

What the cleanup clauses actually do will depend entirely on the target language.

See this document for a bit more context https://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html#cleanups

Comment: Thanks for the emphasis in your answer, I get it now.